# Map boundaries now showing

Tags: dc.js

Hi I've got a map which you can see here:
http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~eeu27a/

The boundaries seem to be missing for states, any idea of what could have caused this?

Thanks

Comment: fwiw I am seeing boundaries just fine (Chrome 58.0.3029.96)

Comment: @RamblinRose If you look at this imgur - http://imgur.com/a/gq0Fy Can you see the difference between the top and bottom photos. The boundaries are displayed around each state with a outline. Do you see the outline without clicking?

Comment: the imgur link does not display boundary lines, and when I click (expand) that image it does not show boundary lines as well. Only the original link displays boundaries...

Comment: @RamblinRose Thanks, I see the boundaries now on my other computer.